# What does it mean that the polarization plane "rotates"?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

Following description are quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rotation).

> "Optical rotation or optical activity (sometimes referred to as rotary polarization) is the rotation of the orientation of the plane of polarization about the optical axis of linearly polarized light as it travels through certain materials."

I can't identify the situation pointed to by the word **“rotation”** in this sentence.

> **My Question:**
>
> - What kind of situation does the "rotation" of this sentence mean?
>     Which is closer to (1), (2) below?
> - Am I right if "While passing through the material, the rotation angle depends on the optical path, but after passing through the material, does it mean close to (2) below as long as it travels in vacuum" ?

---

When we say “rotate” in everyday language, it will have one of the following two meanings. 
In order to distinguish between (1) and (2) below, in this article, we will  name them "Time-dependent rotation" and "Static rotation", respectively.

- (1) Time-dependent rotation: Rotating motion like a feather of a
  pinwheel.
- (2) Static rotation: Like rotation conversion in geometry, once
  rotated to the desired posture, it does not move.

For example, when you said "the rigid body of Fig.1 **rotate** around point $O$ (around an axis perpendicular to the page).

[image]

At this time, the locus of point P on the rigid body is:

When "Rotating" means (1):

$$P(t) = r(cos(\omega t),sin(\omega t)) $$

When "Rotating" means (2):

$$P(t) = r(cos(\theta) , sin(\theta)) \ \  (for\ all\ the\ time\ after \ the \ rotation\ was\ over)$$

**P.S.**
 I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an optically active material rotates the plane by an angle that is proportional to the distance traveled through the material.  As noted in the Wikipedia article you linked to, the angle that the polarization vector rotates through is given by
$$
\Delta \theta = \frac{\pi \Delta n L}{\lambda}
$$
where $\Delta n$ is the difference in the indices of refraction for LH and polarized light (a property of the material), $L$ is the path length the light travels through the material, and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light in vacuum.  You can see that the longer the path length, the farther the polarization angle rotates.

So in this sense, the rotation of the polarization vector as it passes through the medium is closer to your sense (1);  the longer the path length (and the more time the light waves spends in the medium), the greater the rotation.  In other words, the polarization rotates continuously as it passes through the medium.

However, once the light exits the medium into vacuum, it acts like any other light ray and propagates with a constant polarization vector.  So after this point, the light has rotated to some other angle, and the situation is closer to (2) above.

Comment: Thank you for answering.The Japanese word corresponding to the word “rotation” includes both the meanings of 1 and 2. So I was confused. Thanks to that, the confusion has been resolved